# OpenDKIM - cannot determine host's domain name, so skipping default key generation

Tags: linux, centos, opendkim

I've just set up OpenDKIM on my CentOS 6 server but keep getting the following warning each time I start the service:

```
Cannot determine host's domain name, so skipping default key generation.
```

I have my server's hostname and domain name set up in `/etc/sysconfig/network` as well as in `/etc/hosts` but yet it seems that OpenDKIM fails to pick up that info.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Hi there, I am having the same problem. Did you ever fixed this?

Comment: I can't recall as we switched over to a Windows server, but try removing localhosts from both of the files mentioned above - it might help.

Answer (score 2):

Check you /etc/hosts, must like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

93.170.131.123 myhost.com
```

Answer (score -1):

After setting you `/etc/hosts` a restart is required.